How to use Enum with mapped_column in SqlAlchemy
I'm having trouble defining my models with SQLAlchemy, especially when it comes to defining columns of the Enum type.
from enum import Enum
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Table, Uuid, func
from sqlalchemy import Enum as SqlEnum
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship


class DietsEnum(str, Enum):
    VEGETARIAN = "vegetarian"
    VEGAN = "vegan"
    GLUTENFREE = "glutenFree"
    LACTOSEFREE = "lactoseFree"

class PaymentMethodsEnum(str, Enum):
    ONLINE = "online"
    IN_PERSON = "inPerson"


class Meal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "meal"

    meal_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        Uuid(as_uuid=False), primary_key=True, default=lambda _: str(uuid.uuid4())
    )
    diet: Mapped[list[DietsEnum]] = mapped_column(ARRAY(SqlEnum(DietsEnum)), nullable=True)
    
    payment_method: Mapped[PaymentMethodsEnum] = mapped_column(nullable=False)

I'm trying to define them as follows, but I'm encountering an Alembic error when applying my migration. The error message is:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: 
(sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class
'asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedObjectError'>: type "paymentmethodsenum"
does not exist

"What is the correct way to define an Enum type using mapped syntax? Additionally, how can I define a list of Enum types?
I've already tried to use other syntaxes but nothing worked yet.

The error is pretty clear: the enum type has not been created in the database yet. How are you actually creating your tables? Are you using Base.meta.create_all()?
